# Loop through column names in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table called WorkDetails that has the following column names:
*ChargeCode, ,EndShiftDate, A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, C2,......,A10, B10, C10*
All the columns A,B, and C have numeric values representing the hours spent on a task for a particular date.
I am able to write an insert statement like this one:

`insert into myTable
(chargeCode, EndShiftCode, [hours])
select chargeCode, DATEADD(dd, -10, EndShiftCode), sum(A1)
FROM   WorkDetails
Where ChargeCode in (1,2,5)
group by chargeCode, EndShiftCode, A1`

`insert into myTable
(chargeCode, EndShiftCode, [hours])
select chargeCode, DATEADD(dd, -9, EndShiftCode), sum(A2)
FROM   WorkDetails
Where ChargeCode in (1,2,5)
group by chargeCode, EndShiftCode, A2`

The problem is that I have to write it 30 times to change the column name from A1 to A10, B1 to B10, C1 to C10.

Is there a better way to write the insert statements where I can specify the column name to be "Where ColName like 'A%'" by looping through all the columns that start with A, then B, and C?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your rest of the query has same values?

Comment: There is a slightly better way. But first, are you really doing a GROUP BY on the same field that is in the SUM() aggregate function? That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: And are you changing anything besides the column in the SUM() per each column? It looks like you are using a different `DATEADD` value in the two queries (-10 and then -9)?

Comment: The Where clause will be the same for every column that starts with A. It has the same ChargCode. Columns that start with B has different charge code, and columns that start with C has a different charge code.

Comment: The DATEADD will get decremented for every iteration for Columns A, B and C as they are used to get the date the worker worked. A1 to A10 represent working days for a period of time, and to get the date for A1 to A10 it would be EndShiftCode -9, A2: EndShiftCode  -8, A3: EndShiftCode -7 and so forth. Same rule applies to B and C. Thanks!

Comment: So for every Column A[1 - 10], it has 1 specific charge code (i.e. `2`), or a specific list (i.e. `IN (1, 2, 5)`)? For the `DATEADD` decrement value, are you saying that A1, B1, and C1 are all `-9`, and A2, B2, and C2 are all `-8`?

Comment: So for every Column A[1 - 10], it has a specific list (i.e. IN (1, 2, 5). Column B[1-10] different list IN(6,7,8) and C[1-10] another list. "DATEADD decrement value, are you saying that A1, B1, and C1 are all -9, and A2, B2, and C2 are all -8" That is correct. Thanks for the help. Another note to mention is that some columns, for example A5, might not have any hours or entry as the worker might not have worked on that day so it does not need to be inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Dynamic SQL for this. You can just approach the problem from a different (and thankfully also set-based) approach. Just cross-join your query to a numbers/tally table (or create one inline via CTE) for the number of columns (i.e. `TOP(30)` in your case) and then use a CASE statement to pick the column that you want. Each individual value from the numbers table/CTE will represent a row which equates to one of your hard-coded queries. Since each row is a different "query", each one can pull from a different A, B, or C column.

**Test Setup:**

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Bob') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE #Bob;
END;

CREATE TABLE #Bob (
                ChargeCode INT, EndShiftDate DATETIME, A1 INT, B1 INT, C1 INT, 
                A2 INT, B2 INT, C2 INT, A3 INT, B3 INT, C3 INT, A4 INT, B4 INT, C4 INT,
                A5 INT, B5 INT, C5 INT, A6 INT, B6 INT, C6 INT, A7 INT, B7 INT, C7 INT,
                A8 INT, B8 INT, C8 INT, A9 INT, B9 INT, C9 INT, A10 INT, B10 INT, C10 INT
                  );

INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, A1) VALUES (1, '2015-01-05', 1);
INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, A1) VALUES (1, '2015-01-05', 5);
INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, A1) VALUES (2, '2015-01-05', 3);
INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, A1) VALUES (2, '2015-01-05', 56);
INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, A1) VALUES (2, '2015-01-17', 300);
INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, A1) VALUES (2, '2015-01-17', 6);
INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, A1) VALUES (7, '2015-01-17', 10000);
INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, B1) VALUES (10, '2015-01-05', 11);
INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, B1) VALUES (10, '2015-01-05', 15);
INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, B1) VALUES (50, '2015-01-05', 13);
INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, B1) VALUES (50, '2015-01-05', 156);
INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, B1) VALUES (50, '2015-01-17', 1300);
INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, B1) VALUES (50, '2015-01-17', 16);
INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, B1) VALUES (77, '2015-01-17', 100000);
INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, C2) VALUES (200, '2015-02-05', 51);
INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, C2) VALUES (200, '2015-02-05', 55);
INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, C2) VALUES (100, '2015-02-05', 53);
INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, C2) VALUES (100, '2015-02-05', 556);
INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, C2) VALUES (100, '2015-02-17', 5300);
INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, C2) VALUES (100, '2015-02-17', 56);
INSERT INTO #Bob (ChargeCode, EndShiftDate, C2) VALUES (111, '2015-02-17', 1000000);
SELECT * FROM #Bob;
```

**Single, non-Dynamic SQL query:**

```sql
;WITH nums AS
(
  SELECT TOP (6) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [TheNum]
  FROM   [sys].[objects]
), agg AS
(
  SELECT b.ChargeCode,
         DATEADD(DAY, (CEILING(nums.TheNum / 3.0) - 11), b.EndShiftDate) AS [EndShiftDate],
         SUM(
                CASE nums.TheNum
                    WHEN 1 THEN b.A1
                    WHEN 2 THEN b.B1
                    WHEN 3 THEN b.C1
                    WHEN 4 THEN b.A2
                    WHEN 5 THEN b.B2
                    WHEN 6 THEN b.C2
                  --repeat for 7, 8, 9 to be [ABC]3; 10, 11, 12 to be [ABC]4; and so on...
                END
            ) AS [Hours]
  FROM   #Bob b
  CROSS JOIN nums
  WHERE 1 = CASE
              WHEN nums.TheNum % 3 = 1 AND chargeCode IN (1, 2, 5) THEN 1       -- A
              WHEN nums.TheNum % 3 = 2 AND chargeCode IN (10, 50, 70) THEN 1    -- B
              WHEN nums.TheNum % 3 = 0 AND chargeCode IN (100, 200, 500) THEN 1 -- C
            END
  GROUP BY b.chargeCode, DATEADD(DAY, (CEILING(nums.TheNum / 3.0) - 11), b.EndShiftDate)
)
-- INSERT INTO myTable (ChargeCode, [EndShiftDate], [Hours])
  SELECT ChargeCode, [EndShiftDate], [Hours]
  FROM   agg
  WHERE  agg.[Hours] IS NOT NULL;
```

**Results (with the `INSERT` commented out):**

```
ChargeCode  EndShiftDate                Hours
----------  ------------                -----
1           2014-12-26 00:00:00.000     6
2           2014-12-26 00:00:00.000     59
10          2014-12-26 00:00:00.000     26
50          2014-12-26 00:00:00.000     169
2           2015-01-07 00:00:00.000     306
50          2015-01-07 00:00:00.000     1316
100         2015-01-27 00:00:00.000     609
200         2015-01-27 00:00:00.000     106
100         2015-02-08 00:00:00.000     5356
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. The hours added in column A1 did not add up correctly. Also, how do I modify the code to get the DATEADD changed "decremented by one" per each column.

Comment: @user2536008 If you mean that in my example, the A1 hours did not add correctly, they did for me, at least in terms of the variation that I assumed was there. I did not know about the distinct ChargeCode per A / B / C sets so that would change things a little. In order for me to update this to work for you, you need to answer my 2 questions that are in my most recent comment on the question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did answer your questions, but let me explain the desired results again.

Comment: @user2536008 I replied with more question. Please refresh and read all comments on your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did answer your questions, but let me explain the desired results again. I need to sum the values in columns A, B, and C. Columns A1 to A10 have the same chargcode, and they are different  in B and C. The EndShiftDate where I user DATEADD gets decremented by one (starting at number 10 since I have 10 columns that start with A) every time we move to the next column in A, B, or C. For example for Column A1, the EndShiftDate will be -10. Column A2, the EndShiftDate will -9 and so forth. Same for B and C. Column B1, the EndShiftDate  -10. Column B2, the EndShiftDate  - 9.

Comment: @user2536008 I have updated the query based on the info you provided here and in your most recent comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic sql, something like this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''
declare @column varchar(max)

declare cur cursor for select name from sys.columns where object_name(object_id) = 'WorkDetails' and name not in ('chargeCode', 'EndShiftCode')

open cur

fetch next from cur into @column;

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin   
    set @sql = @sql + 'insert into myTable(chargeCode, EndShiftCode, [hours])' + char(13) + char(10) 
        + 'select chargeCode, DATEADD(dd, -9, EndShiftCode), sum({0}) FROM WorkDetails Where ChargeCode in (1,2,5) group by chargeCode, EndShiftCode, {0}'

    set @sql = replace(@sql, '{0}', @column)



   fetch next from cur;
end

select @sql

close cur
deallocate cur
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried it, and ti does not loop through all columns A1 to A10. I just got 30 insert statements generated with the same column name A1. In addition, nothing got inserted in the table.

Comment: Yes, it is not full solution, just some idea. In end of the text you should execute sql: execute sp_sqlexecute @sql

Answer (score 0):

You can use information_schema for minimizing repetitive work of writing queries manually. I prefer writing queries manually over dynamic queries.

i.e.

```
declare @var varchar(8000) = ' insert into .... WHERE ... GROUP BY '
declare @resultQuery varchar(8000) = ''
    select @resultQuery += @var + ' ' + COLUMN_NAME + '; '
    FROM information_schema.columns where table_name = 'myTable'

print @resultQuery
exec (@resultQuery)
```

What you are looking for can be achieved using dynamic query only.

Comment: "What you are looking for can be achieved using dynamic query only." That is not true. Please see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30674716/577765) for an example of how to do this in a single query. Also, `sys.columns` is probably better than using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, coming to me at first thought:

- use exec()
- use pivot / unpivot: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx